# SQL query to take the condition if the value is present

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need a sql query to apply a condition only if the value is present.
For eg. consider the table person

```
sl     Name          city        state
--------------------------------------
1      xxxxxxxx      chennai     TN
2      yyyyyyyy      coimbatore  TN
3      zzzzzzzz      cochin      KL
```

consider the following query

```
select * from person where state = "AD" and city = "visag"
```

will returns 0 rows

i want a query to apply 'state = "AD" and city = "visag"' only if state = "AD" is present.

is there any way to do this in a single select query?

Comment: if not present skip that condition and apply other conditions if there otherwise select all

Answer (score 1):

Whether 'AD' *exists* or not is just another condition:

```
select * 
from person 
where (state = 'AD' and city = 'visag')
or not exists
(
  select * 
  from person
  where state = 'AD'
);
```

Comment: +1 for NOT EXISTS, in my experience it gives better performance and also makes the queries more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from person 
where state = "AD" and city = "visag"
or (select count(*) from person where state = "AD") = 0
```